# Confusion about transistors

Tags: transistors

I'm incredibly new to electronics and tried to make a simple circuit using a transistor. However, whether or not the collector is off while the base is on isn't changing the output except for slightly dimming the attached LED. The transistor is labeled pn2222a, does that mean anything is different about it? What exactly went wrong? Forgive me if I'm just making a silly mistake. The diagram is what I was trying to do, with the switch being me plugging in the wire or not. [image][image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please post us a schematic or crude hand drawing of what your doing. You must have something to guide you...

Comment: The Base-Emitter junction is acting as a forward-biased diode. So current flows thru the 220R resistor, into the base, through the BE junction, out the emitter, and thru your LED.

Comment: Try moving the LED to the collector and switch the transistor on and off by disconnecting the base lead. The base resistor could do with being higher, e.g. something in the range 4.7 kΩ to 10 kΩ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current through the base to the emitter also flows through the LED and activates it. As you can see in your images, despite the collector being disconnected, the LED is still bright but, a little dimmer than when the collector is properly connected.

If you made the base resistor a lot higher than 220 Ω this difference would be more obvious.